# problem with multiview app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiview, uiscrollview

Hi i made an application which has 2 views one paging scroll view which is 430 px heigh and other static view which has 50 px. My problems is a bit hard to understand, i have info button in the static view and if i click on it the program falls due to this:

```
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all kill Current language:  auto; currently objective-c quit Program ended with exit code: 0
```

or

```
2011-03-30 08:51:28.427 PhotoScroller[637:207] -[__NSCFType buttonPressed1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b36db0
2011-03-30 08:51:28.456 PhotoScroller[637:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType buttonPressed1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b36db0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00f2f5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01083313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f310bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00ea0966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00ea0522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x002bc4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x0034c799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0034ec2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x0034d7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x002e0ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x002c1c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x002c6f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x01887992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00f10944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00e70cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00e6df83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00e6d840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00e6d761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x018861c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x01886289 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x002cac93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  PhotoScroller                       0x00001c20 main + 102
    22  PhotoScroller                       0x00001bb1 start + 53
    23  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

but if i use the same code in paging scroll view it works perfectly

parts of my code:

```
UIButton *iButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
iButton.frame = CGRectMake(269.0f, 17.0f, 18.0f, 19.0f);
iButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[iButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
[self.view addSubview:iButton];

-(void)buttonPressed{
    NSLog(@"button pressed in PSV...");
}
```

I do not understand it, I expect that it will work.I just want to understand why it do not works.

static view is subclass of `ViewController`
paging scroll view is subclass of `UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>`

thanks for all the answers.

Comment: i didn't get you??? what selector you are using buttonPressed1 or buttonPressed???

Comment: in paging scroll view i use buttonPressed in static view i use buttonPressed1 and also the name of button variable is iButton1

Comment: did you try by changing the variable name as well as the selector name???

Comment: yes where the selector is called buttonPressed1 the variable name is iButton1 and where the selector is called buttonPressed the variable is called iButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you specify for an action of a button should take a single argument of type id.  So, try changing your selector specification to `@selector(buttonPressed:)` and change your action method to be:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender { ... }
```

Comment: Just try changing your addTarget call to: `[iButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`  and then pass one argument to your buttonPressed method as I showed above.  Hopefully that will help!